# Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.4.0

Tags: android, android-studio

when i import a project and this happened.and i don not konw how to solve it.

this is the console ouput：

```
Error:Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration':app:sampleDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support:support-vectordrawable:25.4.0
Could not get resource'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/suppt-
vector-drawable/25.4.0/support-vector-drawable-25.4.0.aar'.
Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-
vector-drawable/25.4.0/support-vector-drawable-25.4.0.aar'.
Connect to 127.0.0.1:1080 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused
Connection refused
```

Comment: URL is working fine, why is your PC connecting to itself to get the artifacts? Is there a proxy or DNS configuration that you've made?